# How to mass-delete SMS messages that match a pattern?

Tags: iphone, sms

At work, I have a job that sends me a SMS when a critical job fails.  Because of a bug, it ended up sending several hundred SMS messages over the course of a night that I wish to delete.

Is there an easy way to delete just these messages, and keep all other SMS messages?  It would be trivial if there was a way to filter via RegEx; however I do not wish to filter by sender since I want to keep other messages that were sent to me via AT&T's email->sms bridge.

Comment: I'm not even aware of an API for deleting a single SMS. What mechanism are you proposing to delete a message without tapping on the screen to select several and delete them?

Comment: @bmike I have no idea, I thought maybe there was a hidden feature or an app that could do this.  That is why I brought the question here.

Comment: No worries - I was wondering if perhaps you had a head start on the problem. Welcome to the site - I've up voted your question since I hope it gets an answer. Even using a tool like [PhoneView](http://ecamm.com), I've not found a way to delete things, but you're in the right place to find an answer if one is out there.