# How to mass-delete text messages by partially matching phone number on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

Is there a way via an app on iPhone or Mac, to select and delete messages originating from a phone number that matches a pattern?

Specifically, I get many text messages every day from my ZWave deadbolt lock. The number the device uses starts with "1-100", but the remaining digits are always different (but sequential). This makes the messages not cluster together into a conversation which could be easily deleted.

Alternatively, maybe there exists a way to group multiple senders based on a range of numbers, as I can't foresee the actual value of the numbers.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
[This one-year-old thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90422/is-there-a-way-to-mass-delete-sms-messages-that-match-a-pattern) asked a similar question about matching a pattern within a message from same sender. There were no answers, and I wanted to see if there had been any new developments in this direction?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of an App that can delete text messages at all, but I can see it's usefulness in a situation like this.

Furthermore, I don't think there exists a solution to group senders with (partially) unknown numbers, if you new the numbers an ugly and time consuming solution would be to add all possible numbers to one contact, then all messages should hopefully be kept in the same conversation. Your only solution right now seems to be to manually delete the messages :(

Comment: the festure to group senders will be added in iOS 8 maybe this will help you.